# How to get author/Created by information of an item using SharePoint designer 2013 Web service call?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, web-services

I'm trying to make a HTTP Web service call using SharePoint Designer 2013. The URL I'm using is

```
https://<site url>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(My List)/items?$select=id,Created,Author/Id&$expand=Author/Id
```

However, this returns 0 items. If I use

```
https://<site url>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(My List)/items?$select=id,Created
```

this works fine. But as soon as I add Author, it doesn't return anything. How should the url be like for this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the issue. Instead of using Author as a Lookup field I just needed to use AuthorId as normal field. So the url is like

```
https://<site url>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(My List)/items?$select=id,Created,AuthorId
```

This returns the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://<site url>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=Author/Title&$expand=Author
```

Since Author is of type user which is stored as User id in the column when used with expand function it retrives Title of the Author, you can also use ID, FirstName,LastName,LoginName as required.

Comment: Hi Shiva, thanks for the answer. I will try this out. If this works, this'd be better as it gives a way to access other attributes of 'Author'.

Comment: Can you provide some information as to why this is the answer?  Answers should not only provide a solution, but explain the solution, so that others can learn from it.